# Optimize slow custom view in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I have a custom view. It needs to be created many times and added to some list layout.

```
for (final Coupon coupon : sessionCoupons) {
       final StatusCouponView couponView = new StatusCouponView(getContext());
       ...
       couponsListLayout.addView(couponView);
}
```

Creation of each instance takes about 50ms, it's is pretty slow. Most of this time is consumed by `View.inflate` method. How to optimize it?

```
public class StatusCouponView extends FrameLayout {
        public StatusCouponView(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
            initView();
        }

        private void initView() {
            this.listener = null;
            addView(View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_status_coupon, null));
            initViews();
        }

        private void initViews() {
            couponLayoutFront = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_status_coupon_layout_front);
            couponLayoutBack = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_status_coupon_layout_back);
            ...
            couponInfo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view_status_coupon_add_icon);
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**: here is the layout. it has LinearLayouts for back and a front side of the coupon (to flip it in code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_layout_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_view_status_item_top_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_details_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="none">

                <com.appcard.androidterminal.ui.content_view.styleable_view.StyleableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_padding"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </ScrollView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_coupon_info_close" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_layout_front"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_view_status_item_top_margin">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_image_size"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_image_margin_vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_image_margin_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_image_margin_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_image_margin_vertical"
                tools:src="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_coupon_info" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_padding"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_view_status_coupon_padding"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <com.appcard.androidterminal.ui.content_view.styleable_view.StyleableTextView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.88"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_small_text_size"
                tools:text="Save $1.00" />

            <com.appcard.androidterminal.ui.content_view.styleable_view.StyleableTextView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_status_coupon_title"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.88"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_x_x_x_x_x_small_text_size"
                app:styleable_font="bold"
                tools:text="Honey Nut Cheerios" />

            <com.appcard.androidterminal.ui.content_view.styleable_view.StyleableTextView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/view_status_coupon_name"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="on any ONE (1) Windex® Product (excludes travel and trial sizes)" />

            <com.appcard.androidterminal.ui.content_view.styleable_view.StyleableTextView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_expire_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.88"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Expires April 20, 2018" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_add_layout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/main_view_status_item_value_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card_value"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_add_icon"
                    android:layout_width="96dp"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_coupon" />

                <com.appcard.androidterminal.ui.content_view.styleable_view.StyleableTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/main_x_x_small_text_size"
                    app:styleable_color="white"
                    app:styleable_font="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_status_coupon_info_close"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:padding="5dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps use `RecyclerView` rather than whatever `couponsListLayout` is, so you can use fewer instances of the `StatusCouponView`. Beyond that, try to simplify `res/layout/view_status_coupon.xml`. Perhaps post the layout for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid adding the views manually to a Layout in runtime through a loop like you mention in your code snippet.

If you have many objects (as in more than you can fit on your screen), you're better off using a `ViewGroup` that handles recycling views, to avoid creating unnecessary views. You best bet would be `RecyclerView`.

If you view is truly expensive to inflate, you can optimize by using some of the facilities of `RecyclerView` like [prefetching](https://medium.com/google-developers/recyclerview-prefetch-c2f269075710)

However, this is not really addressing your actual problem, you need to make your custom view faster, you should flatten the hierarchy to make the inflation process faster, a very good candidate for that is using `ConstraintLayout` of a `RelativeLayout` if it helps you remove nested layouts.